# How to display previous URL for a string Manipulation Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + document.referrer;
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
    alert(document.referrer);
</script>
```

I cannot display my URL, I am using this method to find keywords if the user enter anything special in search Engines. 
Example Car [Cheapest Car]

Comment: [See this question on the webmasters stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39645/document-referrer-from-google-searches-only-showing-https-www-google-com-no#14131952)

Comment: I read the whole content and its stated about meta content. My main concern is something like a advertisment. Main target is from google to my website.